# Strlen returns unreasonable number

Tags: c++, strlen

If I write:

```
char  lili [3];
cout<<strlen(lili)<<endl;
```

then what is printed is : 11

but if I write:

```
char  lili [3];
lili [3]='\0';
cout<<strlen(lili)<<endl;
```

then I get 3.

I don't understand why it returns 11 on the first part?
Isn't strlen supposed to return 3, since I allocated 3 chars for `lili`?

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out. As the answers explain, if you pass an unreasonable input to a function, you might get an unreasonable output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is because `strlen` works with "C-style" null terminated strings. If you give it a plain pointer or uninitialised buffer as you did in your first example, it will keep marching through memory until it a) finds a `\0`, at which point it will return the length of that "string", or b) until it reaches a protected memory location and generates an error.

Given that you've tagged this C++, perhaps you should consider using `std::array` or better yet, `std::string`. Both provide length-returning functions (`size()`) and both have some additional range checking logic that will help prevent your code from wandering into uninitialised memory regions as you're doing here.

Answer (score 5):

The `strlen` function searches for a byte set to `\0`.  If you run it on an uninitialized array then the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize your array first. Otherwise there is random data in it.

`strlen` is looking for a string termination sign and will count until it finds it.

Answer (score 2):

strlen calculates the number of characters till it reaches '\0' (which denotes "end-of-string").
In C and C++ char[] is equivalent to char *, and strlen uses `lili` as a pointer to char and iterates the memory pointed to by it till it reaches the terminating '\0'. It just so happened that there was 0 byte in memory 11 bytes from the memory allocated for your array. You could have got much stranger result.

In fact, when you write lili[3] = '\0'
you access memory outside your array. The valid indices for 3-element array in C/C++ are 0-2.