# How do i return the size of char array with a function in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char, size

```
void printsize(const char arr[]){
    cout<<"size is: "<<strlen(arr)<<endl;



}    
main(){

    char a[7] = {'a', 'b', 'c','d', 'c', 'b', 'a'};
    printsize(a)

    return 0
}
```

Here is what it will output: size is 11

There is nowhere the array is 11. 
What should I do in order to make the function to output the correct size, which is 7? I do not want to set up a for-loop.

Comment: `strlen` is for null-terminated strings. Your char array doesn't contain a 0 value, so `strlen` runs away and stops at the first 0 somewhere in memory.

Comment: [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) / [`std::strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) work on the convention that the given string is expressed as a sequence of `char`s ending with `\0`. You are getting 11 just by "chance", and actually calling `strlen` on an array not finishing on `\0` produces undefined behavior. Arrays in C/C++ do not hold their length in themselves, look at [`std::string`](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) or [`std::array`](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) for something more advanced.

Comment: Any reason not to use `std::array`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strlen returns unreasonable number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222613/strlen-returns-unreasonable-number)

Answer (score 5):

You can't. Just from `const char arr[]`, how would it know the size of the array? A work-around could be to have a sentinel value. In the case of `strlen`, that sentinel value is a `'\0'` at the end of the string. Add it to your array:

```
char a[8] = { 'a', 'b', 'c','d', 'c', 'b', 'a', '\0' };
```

Also, `a` does not exist in the function, you probably meant to use `arr` instead:

```
std::cout << "size is: " << strlen(arr) << std::endl;
```

This gives you the expected output of `7`. On a side note, you should always declare your `main` function as `int main`. Implicit `int` is discouraged and non-standard, not all compilers support it.

Answer (score 5):

A precondition of `strlen` is that the argument points to a null-terminated array (a character string). Your array is not null-terminated, thereby you violate that precondition by passing (a pointer to) that array into `strlen`.

The behaviour of a program that violates a precondition of a standard function  is undefined.

> How do i return the size of char array with a function in c++?

You can get the size of an array using a template:

```
template <class T, std::size_t N>
std::size_t
size(const T (&array)[N])
{
    return N;
}
```

Usage:

```
char a[7] = {'a', 'b', 'c','d', 'c', 'b', 'a'};
cout<<"size is: "<<size(a)<<endl;
```

Note that you don't need to write this template yourself, since the standard library already provides it for you. It's called `std::size` (introduced in C++17).